# Sniffer shows data sent to a server but I believe it is impossible for my program to send it

Tags: c, sockets

I have a C program the acts as an interpreter between two servers.  Server A send data to my program running on it's own server using socket infd and then my program translates that data and forwards it to server B using outfd. infd is created in main() and for all intensive purposes stays connected for the life of the program.

outfd is declared, connected, written to and finally read from to retrieve the cli prompt returned from server B (which then allows Server B to receive more commands.  Server B does recieve and process these commands properly and at the end of the function call the socket is cleanly shutdown and closed.

All sockets are optioned for NON_BLOCKING with the exception of the listener socket for Server A that returns infd from a call to accept.

The only time I ever write to server A on infd is in response to an "idle" message read from infd.
The "idle" response is declared and sent as follows.

```
//declared in main() and written in main
unsigned char idle[3];  
idle[0]=0xF1;
idle[1]=0x00;
idle[2]=0xFF;

res = write(infd,idle,3);
```

There are no other lines of code in the entire application that write to infd.

When I run a wire trace I see 2 packets one that contains the prompt returned from Server B and the other a DOC CR (x0d) and those packets are coming from my IP / MAC addresses.  When Server A receives this data it enters a state where it doesn't send messages it has queued up until it restarts it's own data interface.

I am not expecting my program to be sending data to Server A other than a hard coded "Idle" message (3 hex characters.  The translated data IS being sent and received by Server B using outfd and it DOES write x0d to outfd but server B receives both writes.

Here is the results of grep on my source for write

```
//This occurs in a called function from main()
int n,outfd;  //this wasn't included in the grep but shows outfd is a local variable not global
n=write(outfd,buf,strlen(buf));  //writes translated data
write(outfd,"\r",1);  //frees up the cli interface of server B

//This occurs in main
res=write(infd,idle,3);
```

note:
In testing I have opened two terminal windows to simulate the Servers.  In the first window I send strings of bytes the represent a couple of messages and an idle message identical to what Server A sends using netcat and redirecting to a hex dump file.  In the other terminal window I use netcat to simulate Server B.

The output onlu shows the idle response message and nothing else

```
  LTR~# hexdump  hex.dat
    0000000 00f1 00ff
    0000003
```

Comment: Off topic...Fun fact for today: You've used an ["eggcorn"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn): "intensive purposes"

Comment: `strlen(idle)` may produce an inadvertent egg corn. The `idle[3]` array shown is only a 1-length string. But you've only shown a teaser of your code.

Comment: From the posted code I will say it's more possible than impossible

Comment: `write` will return the number of bytes written, which may be less than the number you requested.  You need to handle this.